# Avoid making the backup db public when importing into Heroku?

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3

According to Heroku docs, a backup db should be placed into a publicly accessible folder on S3, to allow importing it.

> In order for PG Backups to access and import your dump file you will
>   need to upload it somewhere with an HTTP-accessible URL. We recommend
>   using Amazon S3. Wherever you place the file, ensure that the file is
>   publicly accessible. This may require changing the permissions on the
>   uploaded file. For security, we recommend obscuring the filename and
>   also removing the file once the import has completed.

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

This seems unreasonable from a security standpoint, so I'm wondering if there is a more secure way to import a db.